# Determine the next name for a particular file

Tags: bash

I have to create a script which takes my `<username> _Release $META $PROJECT`

here `META=red`, `PROJECT=green`

Next I need determine the next release name for that `META` and `PROJECT` for your user

eg: `/user/desktop/release/red/green/file_2`
next should be  `/user/desktop/release/red/green/file_3`

So imagine there are many files in that folder so I need to determine which is the highest one is and increment it. I am thinking should I have search all the folders first I am really confused.

Comment: Very interesting, why is your user folder under `/` ? Are you using Mac OS X ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy That would be `/Users/`, no?

Comment: @wjandrea yup, but again, this doesn't look like Ubuntu path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution is to look into that directory for the files and then pick the last one:

```
filename=`find . | sort -t_ -k2 -n | tail -1`
```

then show the new file's name:

```
echo ${filename%_*}_$(( ${filename##*_} + 1 ))
```

let's test it:

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ touch file_{1..999}
$ filename=`find . | sort | tail -1`
$ echo $filename
./file_999
```

Get the file name:

```
$ echo ${filename%_*}
./file
```

Get the number +1:

```
$ echo $(( ${filename##*_} + 1 ))
1000
```

Merge them:

```
$ echo ${filename%_*}_$(( ${filename##*_} + 1 ))
./file_1000
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Pure Bash

```bsh
get_next_release_name()(
    filename_base='file_'

    # Create array with indices based on the filenames.
    for filename in *; do
        index="${filename##$filename_base}"
        filenames["$index"]="$filename"
    done
    
    # Get last item in array and get its index.
    filename_highest="${filenames[-1]}"
    index_highest="${filename_highest##*_$filename_base}"
    
    # Get highest index + 1.
    index_new_highest="$(( $index_highest + 1 ))"
    filename_new="${filename_base}${index_new_highest}"
    
    echo "$filename_new"
)
```

Test:

```
# Create test files.
$ mkdir test &&
>  cd test
$ touch file_{1..999}
$ get_next_release_name
file_1000
```

---

Also here's the equivalent in Python if you want it. I mostly wanted to try it and see how much easier it would be. Turns out it's about as easy, but a lot more straightforward (e.g. less work to get the highest index).

```
import os

filename_base = 'file_'

indices = []
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
  index = int(filename.split(filename_base)[1])
  indices += [ index ]

index_highest = max(indices)
index_new_highest = index_highest + 1
new_filename = filename_base + str(index_new_highest)

print new_filename
```

Also a less verbose version:

```
import os

f_base = 'file_'
indices = [ int(f.split(f_base)[1]) for f in os.listdir('.') ]
print f_base + str(max(indices) + 1)
```