# Bash scripting to create next highest file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

My task is to write a script that creates the next highest file in a particular directory. I have managed to sort the files in the directory so the script outputs the highest file name. For example from files `red_01` `red_02` `red_03` it outputs `red_04`

My next task is to create the highest file so how can I make it create the `red_04` file? Do I need to store the number in a variable and increment it somehow?

Comment: if you have it outputting `red_04` then capture the output in a variable... Then you can `touch $var`. How did you get that output? That seems like the harder part to me!

Comment: Thanks for your reply by going into the directory and passing ls | tail -1 but how would I go about capturing that in to a variable?

Comment: @Zanna [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929386/determine-the-next-name-for-a-particular-file/929394#929394)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you need. Adjust the paths for whatever path you need, could use variables aswell and parse them into the script. But yeah you could adjust it yourself ;)

```
#!/bin/bash
#count your existing files
NUMBERATM=`find ./ -type f -name "red_*" | wc -l`
#add +1 to create the next higher file
NUMBERATM=$((NUMBERATM+1))

#check if it's below 10 since you need the 0 infront of it
if [ $NUMBERATM -lt "10" ]; then
   var=0$NUMBERATM
else
   var=$NUMBERATM
fi

#create your file
touch red_$var
```

Comment: Hmm? This counts the existing files and creates red_XX depending on the amount of files in that directory. This will create red_04 if red_01-03 exists. However if you mean to say that we should only count the red_XX files then just adjust the find command to fit that criteria.

Comment: oh nvm I see my mistake I had a normal file in my test dir aswell, I'll adjust it.

Comment: Great it works :)

Comment: I get an error unless I quote `"red_*"` in the `find` expression (as expected - find globs should be quoted) and I still get `$var` as the number of the last existing file, not the next one...

Comment: @Zanna not sure what you are trying since we add +1 to the counted numbers, so you can't create the same number. But I added the quotes for safety.

Comment: OK, it works when run as a script (provided the filenames don't contain newlines of course, but that's wildly unlikely)

Comment: What I would add of course this script is not fool proof. For example it will fail if you remove a previously created red_XX file. e.g you create red_01-15 delete red_14 it will try to create red_15 again and again. If you want to make it fool proof you will need to create another if case that checks if the file already exists - if it does add another + 1 and check again.

Comment: Or rather create a file with a counter in it and actually use that as a counter of the files previously already generated. Would require a one time creation of the file but would make it fool proof even if you delete previously generated files. But that was not in the requirements of the questioner :)

Comment: @Ria note that this will find all files whose name starts with `red_` in this *and any subdirectories* and it will break if you have a file called `red_foo`, one where the text after `red_` isn't a number.

Comment: True we could use `[0-9]` instead of the `*` so we only find numbers after red.

Answer (score 3):

Without parsing `ls` or `find` output and without creating any extra files, incrementing the name of the last file only (the other files may have any names).

To count files in a directory:

```
stat * --printf "%i\n" | wc -l
```

To get the last file:

```
i=0; j=$(stat * --printf "%i\n" | wc -l); for k in *; do (( (j - ++i) < 1 )) && echo "$k"; done
```

`(( (j - ++i) < 1 ))` this tests how many times the loop has been run and compares it to the number of files in the directory. It relies on the fact that `for` loops over files in an ordered way.

To get the name of the next file assuming the pattern `name_{01..99}`

```
i=0
j=$(stat * --printf "%i\n" | wc -l)
for k in *; do 
  (( (j - ++i) < 1 )) && 
  echo "${k%%_*}"_$(printf %02d "$(( ${k##*_} + 1 ))")
done
```

To create the file:

```
touch $(i=0; j=$(stat * --printf "%i\n" | wc -l); for k in *; do (( (j - ++i) < 1 )) && echo "${k%%_*}"_$(printf %02d "$(( ${k##*_} + 1 ))"); done)
```

or

```
touch $(
  i=0
  j=$(stat * --printf "%i\n" | wc -l)
  for k in *; do 
    (( (j - ++i) < 1 )) &&
    echo "${k%%_*}"_$(printf %02d "$(( ${k##*_} + 1 ))")
  done
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through numbers and check if file already exists.
If it exists, go on with the loop; if file does not exist, create it.

```
for n in $(seq -w 01 99); do
    [[ ! -f "red_${n}" ]] && { touch "red_${n}"; break; }
done
```

Change to `$(seq -w 001 999)` or more digits if needed.

Note: This will create `red_02` if missing, even if `red_01` and `red_03` exist.

Answer (score 2):

This works even if gaps are present and event if numbers are not padded in filenames

```
#!/bin/bash

highest=-1
IFS="   
"
for f in red_*; do
    num=$(echo $f| cut -d _ -f2)
    if [[ ! "$f" =~ red_[0-9]{1,2} ]];then #prevents failing because of                                
                                      #spaces or letters
        num=0
    else
        num=$(printf %d "$((10#$num))"); #eliminate zero padding to prevent 
                                         #interpretation as octal
    fi

    if [[ $num -gt "$highest" ]];then
        highest=$num
    fi
done

newfile=red_$(printf %02d $(($highest+1)))
echo $newfile
touch $newfile
```

--

You could receive both the prefix and the desired amount of zero padding in the output as parameters, eliminating the literals "red_" and "02".

Comment: Your `NUM=$(echo $f| cut -d _ -f2)` will fail if the file name contains a newline (which is a shame since the rest of your script is robust). Just use the shell to remove the bit you don't want: `num=$(printf '%d' "${f##*_}")`. This also removes the need for the second `printf` and uses lower case variable names which are good practice in shell scripts to avoid collision with environmental variables.

Comment: @terdon Your command worked in the command line but I couldn't make it work inside the script, so I changed IFS and filter and pass the names through a regexp to avoid spaces and letters... I guess it's not very concise now, but other than not using parameters (for brevity), its a bit more robust now. Thanx for the feedback.